# Access Symfony Assert in twig view

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assertions, sonata

Try to get the assert value defined in the entity in the view.

Using: 
Symfony 2.8
Sonata Admin: 3.1

I defined a assert in the model like this:

```
 /**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 8,
 *      max = 60,
 *      minMessage = "Longer than {{ limit }}",
 *      maxMessage = "Shorter than {{ limit }}"
 * )
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=60)
 */
private $title;
```

The admin form use a custom formtype to load the custom view:

```
    <?php    
namespace CustomBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TextCountType extends AbstractType
{

    public function getParent()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }


}
```

And the view:

```
   {% block text_count_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
        <script>
         // some custom live validation
         // HERE i need access to the Asserts
     </script>

    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

My question is:
Is there a way to access the asserts in the twig code? 
I do not wan't to redefine it in the admin class for every entity.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say how it will be exactly look like if you are not attaching [form builder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html) but the best way to get these variables (if they're exist) will be dump form object and watch all variables.

```
{{ dump(form) }}
```

Anyway you shouldn't follow this method. The best option will be to write a class formBuilder and in attrs add validation constraints. Depends on type they may be different full list of types you may obtain from [there](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#built-in-field-types) and inside type documentation there should be a full list of attributes available for chosen type.